# How to extract a large JSON object from Firefox's developer console

Tags: json, firefox-developer-tools

I'm working on a webapp, which produces large JSON objects. I log these JSONs via `console.log` and I am looking now for a way to extract these JSONs and store them in a text file.

The actually problem are the sizes of the JSONs.

My approch so far was to store the JSON to a local variable

[image]

And then calling `JSON.stringify(temp0)`. But afterwards firefox will not print the whole string.

[image]

Comment: Write it to a div or textarea element inside the page, instead of logging it to console, and then copy&paste it from there …?

Comment: @CBroe sure, taht would be a workaround. But actually I don't want to manipulate the DOM eacht time I want to extract a json object

Comment: Even an alert window isn't capable to display the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

(i am german - my english is horrible and dont know exact translations - but:)
if its json from "remote" (or local by service) - not generatet inside the script -
then
dont look at tab console -
look at tab networkanalyze
select the script (by url)
and there you get in responsetab all you need -
but this works only with get/post/put etc ....

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to run the stringify operation in the logging code to see the whole thing:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Or make it more human readable with something like

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))
```